# How to change default/place holder Blue Android Icon in Toast, Android 11

Tags: java, android, toast, android-toast, android-11

I'm testing my app on an Android 11 emulator (Pixel 5 API 31), when I open a toast notification I see the following:
[image]

Where the toast has a blue default/place holder android icon next to it. How do I replace this placeholder icon with my own icon?

Older versions of android do not show any icon with the toast message.

My app already has a custom Launcher Icon, Notification Icon and Action Bar and Tab Icons. So it appears it's not inheriting from this, but I can't work out what I need to add or change to replace it with either my own icon or remove it.

This is my java code to launch a toast if required:

```
   Toast.makeText(getContext(),getString(R.string.crashTurnedOn),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You need to create custom toast view. Check out the `getView()` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#getView() method.

Comment: The getView() method is now deprecated with Android 11. It would be great to get an answer to this question; I'm experiencing it with Android 12 (API 31).

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69630124/how-to-configure-toast-icon-in-android-12

Comment: @ChhatrasalSinghBundela so, aren't there way possible to customize a toast message on API level 30 and later, right? Por instance, aren't there how to remove the icon anymore?