# How do i remove default icon from toast while app is targeted to android 12?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Right now app targeted to android 12 or 13 has an image in the toast by default, is it possible to remove that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure Toast icon in Android 12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69630124/how-to-configure-toast-icon-in-android-12)

Comment: duplicate ......................

Answer (score 0):

Gets rid of app icon. Allows message to be a bit longer than default toast, about 3 lines. Follows system theme - dark/light.

Toast XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llCustomToast"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_toast_bg_night"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Toast class

```
public class CustomToast {

    public CustomToast(Context context, String message) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayoutCompat layout = (LinearLayoutCompat) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null);
        AppCompatTextView textView = layout.findViewById(R.id.message);

        if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            layout.setBackground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.custom_toast_bg_night));
            textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
        } else {
            layout.setBackground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.custom_toast_bg_day));
            textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black));
        }

        textView.setText(message);

        Toast toast = new Toast(context);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Call

```
new CustomToast(context, message);
```